# Why can't my php document read in a different folder?

Tags: apache, permissions, ubuntu-14.04

I'm developing a PostgreSQL based site.

If I begin my index.php like

```
<?php
(...)
?>
```

it shows normally on the browser. But if I begin like

```
<?php session_start();
include("../includes/databaseLogin.php");
?>
```

it doesn't show anything at all. I wonder if that's because of 'includes' folder's permission. If I type ls -la at the .. folder, it gives:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Ago  9 20:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Jul 23 11:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Ago  9 20:47 html
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Ago  9 20:46 includes
```

The permissions on the file includes/databaseLogin.php are

```
-rw-r--r--
```

There are 3 R's which means my folder can be READ by myself, by other users on my group, and by other users on other groups, right? Or not? What am I doing wrong here? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the permissions on `includes/databaseLogin.php` itself?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 3 R's again

Comment: If you get no output when at least some output is expected, make sure you have error reporting turned all the way up.  Always when developing and testing code, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script.  No output is often indicative of another fatal error.  Given your file locations and permissions as posted, there should be no errors with this code alone, but any number of other things could go wrong after or during the file inclusion.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelBerkowski, it showed exactly the kind of error I had (I haven't specified a password for the local user; and in the pg_connect I have to specify all 4 parameters: host, dbname, user and password).